# Can I use Phonegap Transition Plugin in Cordova-1.6.0 for Android

Tags: plugins, cordova, transition

When i was used this plugin [ https://github.com/sandstein/phonegap-transition-plugin ] in my android app, i had found a error like **04-18 00:56:02.495: D/CordovaLog(359): [DEPRECATION NOTICE] window.addPlugin and window.plugins will be removed in version 2.0.** How can i will use this plugin. I don't know can i use  phonegap-plugins [ https://github.com/sandstein/phonegap-plugins ] also? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

The Plugin model is being re-architected. The future Cordova 2.0 plugin scheme has not yet been fully defined. Until then, use the deprecated model and ignore the notices.

Comment: Usually when things are deprecated there's already an alternative in place.. oh well. Thanks for this!

Comment: See http://phonegap.com/2012/05/09/phonegap-beliefs-goals-and-philosophy/ for how PhoneGap's release philosophy may be different than you expect

Comment: Thanks Paul. 'The ultimate purpose of PhoneGap is to cease to exist', interesting!